# Select case com subselect e join

Tags: sql, case

Preciso fazer um `select case` com um subselect, é possível? Se sim por favor me informe onde estou errando, senão o que posso fazer neste caso:

```
SELECT m.arquivoordemmov,
       m.contadoragentemov,
       m.datamov,
       m.seqordemmov,
       m.seqproduto,
       m.saldototalmov,
       p.descricaoproduto ,
       CASE
              WHEN m.arquivoordemmov='OC'THEN 'Preço'
                     /*o que preciso é fazer um select dentro do then (select ci.CustoOCItem from OCItem ci join OC c on c.SeqOC=
ci.SeqOC )*/
              from   mov m
              JOIN   movfisica f
              ON     m.seqmovfisica=f.seqmovfisica
              JOIN   oc c
              ON     m.contadoragentemov=c.contadoragenteoc
              JOIN   produto p
              ON     m.seqproduto=p.seqproduto
              WHERE  m.arquivoordemmov='OC'
              AND    c.situacaooc='FECHADA'
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer uma subquery no `case when`. No seu caso como só tem um case poderia simplesmente fazer um join:

```
SELECT m.arquivoordemmov,
       m.contadoragentemov,
       m.datamov,
       m.seqordemmov,
       m.seqproduto,
       m.saldototalmov,
       p.descricaoproduto,
       ci.CustoOCItem,
 from  mov m
 JOIN  movfisica f ON m.seqmovfisica=f.seqmovfisica
 JOIN  oc c ON m.contadoragentemov=c.contadoragenteoc
 JOIN  produto p ON m.seqproduto=p.seqproduto
 JOIN  OCItem ci on ci.SeqOC = c.SeqOC
WHERE  m.arquivoordemmov='OC'
  AND  c.situacaooc='FECHADA'
```

Agora o case faria sentido se tivesse um comportanto diferente para cada valor, por exemplo assim:

```
CASE WHEN m.arquivoordemmov='OC' THEN (
         select ci.CustoOCItem 
           from OCItem ci join OC c on c.SeqOC=ci.SeqOC)
ELSE 'Preço'
END AS Alias
```

Pode ver um exemplo desse case funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/687ac2/3